# BeautifulSoup returning different html than view source

Tags: python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm brand new to using BeautifulSoup, so forgive me if my question is stupid. However, I've been googling and trying suggestions in every stackoverflow thread I could since 6am, but to no avail.

My problem is that I have a .csv file with gene names, some of them are in ensEMBL format, which means I MUST use the ensembl database to lookup the info I need. For the rest I can use the ncbi database.

Now, my code is just fine. I know this because every query sent to ncbi returns the info I need, and I'm able to extract it all with BeautifulSoup and output it to a csv. HOWEVER, either urlopen or BeautifulSoup are not working the way I've been led to understand they work.

When I put the following URL into my address bar, the correct webpage loads: http://uswest.ensembl.org/Gallus_gallus/Gene/Summary?db=core;g=ENSGALG00000016955;r=1:165302186-165480795;t=ENSGALT00000027404.

I can then view source and check out the HTML. Yet when I have:

```
html = urlopen(http://uswest.ensembl.org/Gallus_gallus/Gene/Summary?db=core;g=ENSGALG00000016955;r=1:165302186-165480795;t=ENSGALT00000027404, 'lxml')
```

The HTML it outputs is not at all what I get when I load the same URL in my browser and view source. I know that for pages with javascript, inspect element and view source will be different, but urlopen should ALWAYS return the same HTML as view source.

I need to extract the string after "Description". Visiting the link in my browser, I can inspect source and see the tags I need to find with BeautifulSoup; however, unless urlopen works properly and returns the correct HTML, there is nothing I can do. My RA job depends on getting this done by tonight.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parts of the page are loaded by the Javascript that is referenced in the script tag, for instance the "Summary". However the text you are looking for is embedded in the HTML. Locating the text after the Description tag works with this code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://uswest.ensembl.org/Gallus_gallus/Gene/Summary?db=core;g=ENSGALG00000016955;r=1:165302186-165480795;t=ENSGALT00000027404"
r = requests.get(url, timeout=5)
html = BeautifulSoup(r.text)
description = html.find("div", {'class': "rhs"})
print description.text
```

Comment: That worked marvelously. Since I'm brand new to web-crawling / scraping, any bits of information really help. Could you share why "requests.get(url)" and html = BeautifulSoup(r.text) returns the HTML I see when I right-click and view source, but html = openurl(ensemblURL) did not? Thank you kindly.

Comment: Well, I don't know and I don't intend to investigate but everyone is using the requests module these days instead of urllib, because it's far easier to use. I am quite sure you could make it work with urllib but why go through that hassle?

Comment: Also please be so kind to mark my answer as correct.

Comment: Sorry for not marking it! New to stack exchange, and when I saw that I couldn't upvote your answer, I assumed I could not do anything else with it. Would you recommend that I replace all use of urllib2 with requests, even the ones where urllib2 works?

Comment: I think I would do that. This would presumably also simplify your code.