# Beautifulsoup response does not match with view source code output

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

While comparing response from code and chrome source code. I observe that response returned from beautifulsoup does not match with page source code. I want to fetch class="rc"and I can see the class with "rc" on page source code, but could not find it in the response printed. I checked with "lxml" and "html.parser" too.

I am beginner in python so my question might sound basic. Also, I already checked few articles related to my problem([BeautifulSoup returning different html than view source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26763461/beautifulsoup-returning-different-html-than-view-source)) but could not find solution.

Below is my code:

```
import sys, requests
import re
import docx
import webbrowser
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

query = sys.argv
url = "https://google.com/search?q=" + "+".join(query[1:])
print(url)
res = requests.get(url)
# print(res[:1000])

if res.status_code == 200:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, "html5lib")
    print(type(soup))
    all_select = soup.select("div", {"class": "rc"})
    print("All Select ", all_select)
```

Comment: This comes up frequently (several times a month?). Some content is dynamic which includes some classes for example. There are many examples on SO to help you with this.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, try using another parser such as "lxml" instead of "html5lib".