# Python, How to parse HTML from URL?

Tags: python, html-parsing

I have Python code that can parse data from a string variable containing HTML code.

I want code that gets the HTML from URL and then parses this data.

the working code (parsing HTML):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = '''\
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="generator"
     content="HTML Tidy for HTML5 (experimental) for Windows https://github.com/w3c/tidy- 
      html5/tree/c63cc39" />
    <title></title>
   </head>
 <body>
<div class="Eqh F6l Jea k1A zI7 iyn Hsu">
  <div class="Shl zI7 iyn Hsu">
    <a data-test-id="search-guide" href="" title="Search for &quot;living room colors&quot;">
      <div class="Jea Lfz XiG fZz gjz qDf zI7 iyn Hsu" style="white-space: nowrap; background-color: 
         rgb(162, 152, 139);">
        <div class="tBJ dyH iFc MF7 erh tg7 IZT mWe">Living</div>
       </div>
      </a>
     </div>
    </div>
  </body>
 </html>
 '''
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')
a = soup.select('div.Eqh.F6l.Jea.k1A.zI7.iyn.Hsu a')[0]
print(a['title'])
```

Here is what I have tried that does not work (getting HTML from URL and then parsing):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

vgm_url = 'https://www.pinterest.com/search/pins/?q=skin%20care'
html_text = requests.get(vgm_url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, 'html.parser')
a = soup.select('div.Eqh.F6l.Jea.k1A.zI7.iyn.Hsu a')
for a in soup.select('div.Eqh.F6l.Jea.k1A.zI7.iyn.Hsu a'):
    print(a['title'])
```

I'm not getting any error, it does not print anything.
I appreciate your help.

Comment: Are you _really_ sure that `html_text` has the text that you want? That is, it contains the contents you want instead of, say, a login page?

Answer (score 1):

Then in the debugging process use `print(html_text)` to see what you are getting ;).

When you print it you see that it is different from the page source (see it in Chrome or other webbrowser and go to the url). You can also see that the page is loading for a bit when you go to it in a browser.

Therefore you need to wait for it to load with something like [Selenium](https://pythonbasics.org/selenium-wait-for-page-to-load/).

To demonstrate a bit of Selenium, I loaded your page and clicked something with a defined class that loaded after a while:

```
# you will have to install (Chrome), or another browser driver
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = Chrome(r'C:\Program Files\chromedriver.exe')  # I have (Chrome) installed here

driver.get("https://www.pinterest.com/search/pins/?q=skin%20care")
feeling_lucky_btn = WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(  # waiting for loading
    EC.presence_of_element_located(
    (By.CLASS_NAME, 'GrowthUnauthPinImage__Image')))  # identifiing element by class name
feeling_lucky_btn.click()
```

Comment: thanks for the response, ya, but I want the proper result, the result that the code does, just print out long HTML codes won't solve my problem, unless you have a hint on how to use it.

Comment: If the `html_text` is the same as `data` (your example), and your example works, then what you tried has to work as well, right?

Comment: thanks for the response, I was looking at the print result, long HTML code, there was not the code that supposes to be, I am confused now.

Comment: Yeah, so you need to wait for a bit for the JavaScript to load, right?

Comment: @Brambor Is this even possible with `requests`? I think he needs to use `selenium`? Isn't it? I see his soup has just 1 main div in it. Nothing else.

Comment: @Brambor thanks for the response, I am not sure how to do that, when I run the Py file, it takes a few sec and returns nothing. when I run it with the print html_text, it does print immediately,

Comment: @Dave99 Abrar is saying correctly, you cannot do that with `requests` (I believe), you need something like [selenium](https://pythonbasics.org/selenium-wait-for-page-to-load/). However, it is pretty cool, I made online game bot with it :D.

Comment: thanks for the response, in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26763461/beautifulsoup-returning-different-html-than-view-source) suggesting to use another kind of response, because of the same issue, I tried it and it does not work and it gives me 'TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable'

Comment: @Dave99 Sometimes you have to not only wait but simulate user presence. Selenium is good for that.

Comment: @Brambor thanks for the response, I got help with the above code to make it work, Now if I am supposed to use Selenium to make it work using URL, can you help me with the exact code with Selenium? I have not used Selenium. for example, I am not sure if I can use Select with Selenium, or it has completely different functionality. thanks.

Comment: @Dave99 I added demo for Selenium to my answer ;).

Comment: @Dave99 Did it work or do you require further instructions?